# How to fix 'Object not usable' in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component called *EditorComponent* that calls a function from an angular service.

```
export class EditorComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private crudService: CrudService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.crudService.readProject();
  }
}
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CrudService {
  connection: WebSocket;

  constructor() {
    this.connection = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8888/kritiq", "json");
  }

  readProject(): void {
    try {
      this.connection.send("READ PROJECT");
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
}
```

The *readProject()* method fails with:
`"An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable"`

I don't get what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Could you show the complete code for the CrudService. All angular services that you want to use via dependency injection needs the @Injector() decorator

Comment: Added the complete code from the <crud.service.ts> file.

Comment: looks like `new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8888/kritiq", "json")` may not have been successful

Comment: I thought about that but I placed a _console.log(this.connection)_ at the start of the _readProject()_ function and it logs indeed an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the `WebSocket` is not in an `OPEN` readyState.  If you set a 2 second timeout inside your `readProject()` function and call `this.connection.send(...)` after 2 seconds, it will work.

Ultimately you need to wait until the connection is completely open before you call `readProject()`.

I put together a stackblitz demonstrating this.

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5najlm
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#Constants

---

### EDIT (providing a possible solution)

A possible solution is to use an observable in your `CrudService` to determine when the connection is open.  In you component where you want to call `readProject()` will subscribe to the connection state observable and when the state changes to open, only then you call `readProject`

#### crud.service.ts

```
export class CrudService {

  public connection: WebSocket;
  
  private connectionStateSubject: BehaviorSubject<WebSocketState> = 
    new BehaviorSubject<WebSocketState>(WebSocketState.CLOSED);
  
  public connectionState: Observable<WebSocketState> = 
    this.connectionStateSubject.asObservable();

  constructor() {
    this.connection = new WebSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org');
    this.connection.onopen = (event) => this.onOpen(event);
    this.connection.onmessage = (event) => this.onMessage(event);
    this.connection.onclose = (event) => this.onClose(event);
  }

  readProject(): void {
    this.connection.send("READ_PROJECTS");
  }

  onMessage(event: any) {
    console.log(event);
  }

  onOpen(event: any) {
    this.connectionStateSubject.next(WebSocketState.OPEN);
  }

  onClose(event: any) {
    this.connectionStateSubject.next(WebSocketState.CLOSED);
  }

}
```

#### editor.component.ts

```
export class EditorComponent implements OnInit  {

  public states: string[] = [];
  
  constructor(private _crudService: CrudService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._crudService.connectionState.subscribe((state: WebSocketState) => {
      if (state === WebSocketState.OPEN) {
        this._crudService.readProject();
      }
    });
  }

}
```

#### websocket-state.enum.ts

```
export enum WebSocketState {
  OPENING,
  OPEN,
  CLOSING,
  CLOSED
}
```

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mlukb1

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked like a charm. Your thorough explanation really helped!